# Hide <project>_automoc targets in CMake

Tags: c++, xcode, visual-studio-2015, cmake, qt5

I am trying to use the CMAKE_AUTOMOC property to automatically find and compile mocable files.

However, the command `set( CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON )` also includes the generated _automoc.cpp file in the Visual Studio "Source Files" filter. This is a problem for two reasons :

- It creates the filter even if it was not used before, and therefore pollutes VS explorer.
- It adds an additionnal file that should not be manually modified to the solution, in the middle of other source files.

I would like to know if it possible to :

1) Prevent CMake from including this file to the Visual Studio filters. I searched and found https://cmake.org/Bug/print_bug_page.php?bug_id=13788.
However using

```
SET_PROPERTY(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)
SET_PROPERTY(GLOBAL PROPERTY AUTOMOC_FOLDER automoc)
```

did not change anything to my problem.

2) Remove a given entry from the .vcxproj.filters file using CMake, using a command similar to

```
source_group( "Source Files" FILES "filepath" )
```

which is used to add the entry "filepath" to the "Source Files" filter.

I am currently using CMake 3.5, VS 2015 and Qt 5.6. Here is a shortened version of the CMake that reproduces the problem :

```
project( myproj )

# Some stuff to include Qt libraries
# ...

set( CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON )

# These 2 lines don't change anything
SET_PROPERTY(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)
SET_PROPERTY(GLOBAL PROPERTY AUTOMOC_FOLDER automoc)

# Create project
add_executable( ${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp" )
```

In the VS filter named "Source Files", I can see main.cpp and myproj_automoc.cpp, which does not even exist before the first compilation (trying to open it with VS sends an error "Cannot open the file"). In myproj.vcxproj.filters there is an entry :

```
Include="C:\pathto\build\myproj_automoc.cpp">
<Filter>Source Files</Filter>
```

which shouldn't be here since I did not ask for it.

Am I missing something ?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: it might help if you included the cmake file stripped to bare minimum but still reproducing your problem. My wild guess is that you set your sources with a wildcard and build in-source, but that can be totally off.

Comment: I included the few lines that reproduce the problem in the first post. I am not building in-source and even if I don't use wildcards to set the sources (like in my example), the _automoc.cpp file is included (whether the file exists or not). Sources ("main.cpp") and the CMakeList are in a different directory from the build directory.

Comment: hmmm.... strange, try to put project() to the top and clean the cmake cache.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I already tried (and just retried to be sure) and it doesn't change anything. When I set CMAKE_AUTOMOC to ON, CMake automatically creates an entry in VS filters corresponding to "build\myproj_automoc.cpp" with the filter name "Source Files".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had trouble getting this to work as documented as well.  It looks like they renamed the variable in one of the releases.  As of Cmake 3.0.2, you can do the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(MyProj CXX)
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY AUTOGEN_TARGETS_FOLDER MyAutoMocFolder)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    ${MyProj_HEADERS}
    ${MyProj_SRCS}
    ${MyProj_QRC}
    ${MyProj_UI})
```

Note that you have to use set_property and the property name is now AUTOGEN_TARGETS_FOLDER.

In Xcode, this puts the generated _automoc folders in the "MyAutoMocFolder" instead of littering the parent folders with them.  In Visual Studio the automoc folders in the folder as well.

It doesn't however hide the project_automoc.cpp files that are generated.  To move those you have to define a source group, as Armand pointed out:

```
source_group( MyAutoMocFolder FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}_automoc.cpp )
```

Comment: I tried using AUTOGEN_TARGETS_FOLDER instead of AUTOMOC_FOLDER and it did not work on my projects, CMake still automatically sends the _automoc files in the "Source Files" visual studio filter. For now, I am using the following workaround :

`source_group( MyAutoMocFolder FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}_automoc.cpp )`
This filters the myproj_automoc files out of the "Source Files" directory.

Comment: Updated the answer with your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

As of CMake 3.9, you can use [`AUTOGEN_SOURCE_GROUP`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/AUTOGEN_SOURCE_GROUP.html) to filter MOC files.

```
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY AUTOGEN_SOURCE_GROUP "Generated Files")
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you. How did you figure out to use set_property? I've been struggling with this documentation for a long time until I saw your answer

Comment: @Johnathon CMake documentation of [`set_property`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_property.html) states how you can use it. The usage can be `(GLOBAL PROPERTY ...)` or `(TARGET my_target PROPERTY ...)` etc. The documentation also redirects to [cmake-properties](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-properties.7.html#manual:cmake-properties(7)) page where you can see the list of properties of global scope or on targets etc. Sadly, the documentation lacks some examples. I mostly refer to similar commands and modify them.